# A bijection from the plane to itself that takes a circle to a circle must take a straight line to a straight line.

Tags: geometry, functions

Let $ f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} $ be a bijective function. If the image of any circle under $ f $ is a circle, prove that the image of any straight line under $ f $ is a straight line.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: This problem was a question some of my classmates and I discussed over tea-time. We have regular discussions like this. Have you seen it somewhere before?

Comment: Mostly I'm wondering if you happen to know for a fact that this is true (e.g. because it was stated in a book of problems somewhere) or just believe it to be true.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was obtained from a book. However, someone in my group mentioned that this was a folklore result and that he had seen a proof of it in some article. None of the rest of us could find a proof ourselves, and that fellow had trouble remembering the article where he had seen the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://www.math.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no66.pdf) has the result (second page).  I hope it's thorough enough to placate your curiosity...

Comment: Thanks! You've provided a very nice pancake indeed.